# JSON: reading big json object return undefined

Tags: json

I am trying to read a big JSON object in `node.js` app. I am getting the object in variable called data.

Then I am trying to `console.log(data.weatherdata)` the result is `undefined`. However, the JSON object is valid and it works fine on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15rk91em/)

Comment: for me everything is ok

Comment: Yes, it's completely weird if `console.log(data)` it works fine when i do `console.log(data.weatherdata)` it return undefined.

Comment: both are good for me

Comment: Yes the question is if your 'json' is not string ... if yes you should JSON.parse it first

Comment: I can not believe i was that dumb it works when parse the object user `JSON.parse`

Comment: The easiest solution is always almost the best : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem occurs on the server side? are you sure that your object is correctly parsed? Have you tried calling `Json.parse` on data before trying to `console.log(data.weatherdata)`?